# How to debug binary which doesn't have executable flags?

Tags: linux, lldb

I'm trying to debug the binary which is not executable.

As sample I'm using `/bin/true` with 644 permission:

```
install -m 644 /bin/true .
```

and I'm trying to run it as:

```
$ lldb true
(lldb) target create "true"
Current executable set to 'true' (x86_64).
(lldb) process launch
```

But I've got the following error:

> error: error: ::posix_spawnp ( pid => 29052, path = '/Foo/Bar/true', file_actions = 0x7fff5d015e98, attr = 0x7fff5d015ed8, argv = 0x7fd6396507f0, envp = 0x7fd6396512d0 ) err = Permission denied (0x0000000d)

Is it something possible using lldb without giving the executable flag to the binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `lldb` wants to run the program using a combination of `fork` and `exec`, then control the progam with `ptrace`. But the kernel will refuse to `exec` the program unless it has the correct x bit (your user/group ids define which one is the correct one) set. You can set the x bit for yourself, the owner, only (if you want to prevent others from executing the binary); or you can set the x bit, start the process, and remove the x bit again (if you want to prevent yourself from running it accidentially). But to start a process that runs the binary, you need the x bit.

If you really really want to execute the binary's code without setting it executable, you could probably write a program to read its header, `mmap` the sections you need, read the binary into those sections, possibly fix up relocations, and jump to the entry point. But you'll have a long, arduous way in front of you to get this right, and it probably won't be possible to get `llvm` recognize any symbols in the binary. So while doing this might be a theoretical possibility, there's really no point in trying.

Answer (score 2):

As for workaround (per this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83862/21471)), on Linux the non-executable binary can be invoked by dynamic linker/loader as below:

```
lldb -- /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 foo_binary
```

and for 32-bit version use `ld-linux.so` found in `/lib` instead.